# Wordpress htaccess rewriterule without changing URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In WordPress I'm using the Events Manager plugin, which uses the /events/subpage path in the URL.

I need to tweak things slightly so that /courses/subpage rewrites to /events/subpage i.e. the content of /events/subpage is shown when going to /courses/subpage.  The URL should stay as /courses.

I thought this rule would do it:

```
RewriteRule ^courses/?(.*)$ /events/$1 [L]
```

But the URL changes from /courses to /events so it looks like my rule isn't quite right.

EDIT
Strangely I can put anything in place of /courses and it resolves to /events anyway. Confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I’ve cracked it.

I uninstalled the rewrite plugin and replaced it with Rewrite Rules Inspector. Then I added the following to functions.php
add_rewrite_rule(‘^course/([^/]*)/?’, ‘index.php?event=$matches[1]‘, ‘top’); // single event

In Rewrite Rules Inspector is said the rule was missing. I flushed the rules using the plugin and everything appears to be working now. It looks like the original rewrite plugin wasn’t flushing the rules properly.